# How to check service-to-service authentication in Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints, microservices, google-oauth

I'm trying to split a monolith Google App Engine application (using Python & standard environment) into several services within one application. Default service is calling API implemented using the Endpoints framework in another service.

Everything works nicely except that I don't understand how to correctly check authentication of the default service (and make it work both in local development server and in production).

To call the service I'm using `google-api-python-client` and default application credentials.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
service = build(
    name, version,
    credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default(),
    discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url)
service.client_token().execute()
```

My service API code looks like the following

```
@endpoints.api(
    name='test',
    version='v1',
)
class TestApi(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        TestResponse,
        path='test',
        http_method='GET',
        name='test')
    def get_test(self, request):
        # user = endpoints.get_current_user()
        # if not user:
        #     raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException
        return TestResponse(test='test')
```

In production `endpoints.get_current_user()` seems to return a correct application user, but I don't know how to correctly validate that it's the same application. In local development environment `endpoints.get_current_user()` returns `None`.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem yet? :) I'm very curious if you did

Comment: @KingReload yes, it turned out to be a fairly simple thing. I had to generate swagger file and deploy it. I'll try to post detailed answer later today.

Comment: glad you were able to resolve it on your own ^^ and notify me about the post :) I'm very curious

Answer (score -1):

You're doing it wrong. You're defining `user`, but not using it.

The following **example** greets a user who has signed in to the app with a personalized message and a link to sign out. If the user is not signed in, the app offers a link to the sign-in page for Google Accounts.

If you use the `from google.appengine.api import users` module:

```
def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        nickname = user.nickname()
        logout_url = users.create_logout_url('/')
        greeting = 'Welcome, {}! (<a href="{}">sign out</a>)'.format(nickname, logout_url)
    else:
        login_url = users.create_login_url('/')
        greeting = '<a href="{}">Sign in</a>'.format(login_url)

    self.response.write('<html><body>{}</body></html>'.format(greeting))
```

When creating a `user` you still need to check if it's empty or not. Plus `user` stores different values. So you just need to make a call to them and define them.

If you have pages that require the user to be signed in in order to access, you can enforce this in your [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#handlers_login) file.

By default, your app will use Google Accounts for authentication. To choose another option, such as Google Apps domain, go to the [settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/start?pli=1&project=randombrowser-1493197222634) page for your project in the Google Cloud Platform Console and click `Edit`. In the Google authentication `dropdown menu`, select the desired authentication type, and then click `Save`.

---

You could however also use the [Tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) framework.

Comment: I'm using Google Cloud Endpoints and want to check authentication using mechanisms it provided.

Comment: @Fedor then you should've described that in your question, as you don't refer to it, this should be A solution to the problem, but thanks for reviewing my answer :) appreciate it