# Clarification on Google App Engine Standard Environment Service to Service Authentication with Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Related questions:

1. [How to do authentication check in Python library from Google Cloud Endpoints on GAE standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647661/how-to-do-authentication-check-in-python-library-from-google-cloud-endpoints-on)
2. [How to check service-to-service authentication in Google Cloud Endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792085/how-to-check-service-to-service-authentication-in-google-cloud-endpoints)

I have an App Engine Standard (Python) environment (using webapp2) that will be making calls to a Cloud Endpoint (no user authentication required, but the calls must be service-to-service secured) and I would like some clarification on how to do this using the Cloud Endpoint Framework for App Engine Standard.

If I go about the method described in (2) above, does this mean I would have to manual edit the openapi.json file that is generated from `lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_openapi_spect` with the security definitions? The documentation seemed geared more towards GCE and App Engine Flex environments that are using the Cloud Endpoints for OpenApi so it was confusing whether I had to edit my `@endpoints.api` configurations.

Or, given that I am making a call from App Engine Standard environment, would I just be able to use urlfetch and AppIdentity: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/ and assert identity to the endpoint? If so, what would the configurations look like?